# Importing from outside webpack (runtime importing)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack

> This is just something I thought today and I didn't see a lot of information so I'm going to share this *weird* cases and how **I personally** solved them (if there's a better way please comment, but meanwhile this might help others ^^)

In a webpack bundle, every `import`/`require` you do, is managed by webpack using their internal `require` function. That means you cannot use anymore the original NodeJS global `require` if you are inside a webpack bundle.

> See also: [Exporting from outside webpack bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215470/exporting-outside-webpack/58215471)

Comment: Related: https://hackernoon.com/building-isomorphic-javascript-packages-1ba1c7e558c5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a workaround provided by webpack actually:

A variable called `__non_webpack_require__` which is the original `require` so, in your code, you can do this:

```js
const internalModule = require('internal/module');
// or import internalModule from 'internal/module'; in the ES6 way

const externalModule = __non_webpack_require__('external/module');
```

If you are using TypeScript, you can add this line in your `global.d.ts` file to avoid syntax errors:

```
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequireFunction;
```

> **Fact 1:** Actually after the build, you can see how your commonly used `require` (webpack's) has been renamed to `__webpack_require__`, and that `__non_webpack_require__` has been preserved as the original `require`.
>
> **Fact 2:** Webpack also use the original `require` to import modules from the system (not bundled with the code), such as `net`, `events`, `fs`, etc.

Comment: Interesting. So are you saying that __non_webpack_require__ is globally accessible at runtime, to access any individual module? e.g.,

`<script>var $ = __non_webpack_require__ ('jquery');</script>`

Of course this would also depend on which modules exist in the resulting build? Anyway, I think the answer to my question here is "no," but I'm looking for some clarification, as I'm still learning the depths of Webpack, coming from the RequireJS universe.

Comment: @JasperTey the `__non_webpack_require__` would be the native nodeJS `require`, in server side of course