# Exporting outside webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack

> This is just something I thought today and I didn't see a lot of information so I'm going to share this weird cases and how I personally solved them (if there's a better way please comment, but meanwhile this might help others ^^)

In a regular module, you would do something like this to export your function/library/object/data:

```js
// regular NodeJS way:
module.exports = data;

// ES6 way
// (will get transpiled to the regular way using the module variable by webpack)
export data;
default export data;
```

When compiling the library usually `babel` or `tsc` are used, but if for any reason you want not only to compile (transpile) your library but also pack it using webpack, you will encounter this case.

As you know, in a webpack bundle the `module` variable is local to the bundle (every module/file gets wrapped with a function where `module` is a parameter = local variable), so nothing really gets exported outside the bundle, is just nicely managed by webpack.

That means that you can't also access the contents using the regular require/import methods.

In some case you might find necessary to export **outside** webpack. (i.e. you are trying to build a library using webpack and you want it to be accessible by other people). This basically means you need to access the original `module` variable, but webpack doesn't expose it like it happened with `__non_webpack_require__`.

> See also: [Importing runtime modules from outside webpack bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215361/importing-from-outside-webpack-runtime-importing/58215363)

Comment: Have you thought about using https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals  this allows you to exclude / whitelist etc.

Comment: @Keith thanks for the suggestion. But I think that covers a different problem: excluding modules from the build. What this question is related to is about exporting outside the webpack bundle (so that something can be imported from somewhere else)

Comment: Oh, right yes.  In that case I would normally just put it on the `globalThis`

Comment: True, that's a way, like setting a global object in `window` in case of the browsers... but it's setting a global object... :-/

Comment: But isn't that what your doing, your setting a global called -> `__non_webpack_module__`  .  `This will allow to import it as usual from other files`, when you say normal, what do you mean here?.  IOW: doing -> `globalThis.__non_webpack_module__` would be identical.

Comment: yes, you are right. And also by the only fact of using webpack you are setting another global (webpack function)... but it's not the same setting only one variable for your environment than setting one per each module. Anyways your solution is completely acceptable and usable, but it doesn't allow that data to be imported as a module from the file. I'm just proposing more solutions in case it's useful based on my experience after researching :)

Comment: Right, I think I see where your coming from now.  You mean so you can use built in ES6 loaders?.  In that case have you looked at `libraryTarget` & `libraryExport` that is specially designed so that you can export your functions etc to 3rd party.   Basically setting `libraryTarget = 'umd'` will  make it work pretty much everywhere.  IOW: if you loaded with an ES6 compatible browser no global is touched, on the other hand an ES5 browser could still then use the global.  So, kind of best of both world.s

Comment: Yes haha, I guess my case was a bit special, complex. I have different targets in only one build. The main file is just an executable so the regular build is ok, but inside that I'm still building some modules like this... so there's no way to do it with standard webpack features... in a single build process.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create our own `__non_webpack_module__` (as webpack does with [`__non_webpack_require__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215361/importing-from-outside-webpack-runtime-importing/58215363#58215363).

How I did it is using `webpack.BannerPlugin` to inject some code **outside** the bundle. This code is prepended to the build *after* the minification is done, so it's preserved safely.

In your `webpack.config.js`:

```js
plugins: [
  new BannerPlugin({
    raw: true,
    banner: `const __non_webpack_module__ = module;`,
  }),
]
```

And again, if you are using TypeScript, in `global.d.ts`:

```
declare const __non_webpack_module__: NodeModule;
```

And now, you can do something like this in your code:

```js
__non_webpack_module__.exports = /* your class/function/data/whatever */
```

This will allow to import it as usual from other files

> **Tip:** You might want to look at [BannerPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/banner-plugin/) to check other options, like `include` or `exclude` so this variable is only generated on the desired files, etc.